# Can't I delete files in the Startup folder in Windows 10

Tags: batch-file

So far, I've been able to mess around in the Startup folder with little worry. For a basic script to mess with a pal of mine, I decided to make a script in parts that deletes the one before it.

```bat
copy "Song2.exe" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Song2.exe" >nul
del "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Song1.exe" >nul
copy "Part3.exe" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Part3.exe" >nul
shutdown.exe /r /t 00
del %0
```

However, upon testing this, I found that it denied access to deleting from Startup -- something that, up until now, hasn't happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work when you right click on the batch file and choose `Run as Administrator`?

Comment: @Compo Yes, it does -- however, I'd need to find a way to have it do this automatically, since I need this program to run each Startup.

Comment: The answer to your question then is that you aren't running your batch file with sufficient privileges to perform the tasks you require of it! Are you expecting us to tell you how to automatically bypass Windows security settings?